# Pruebas Comportamiento Bateria App Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, test, rendimiento

Cordial saludo, estoy en desarrollo de una aplicación con Xamarin Forms; para la plataforma de Android, y requiero realizar pruebas del comportamiento de la bateria cuando esta en ejecución la Aplicación.

Como puedo realizar este tipo de Pruebas. Es posible desde el AppCenter?. Agradezco la colaboración.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase **Battery** está disponible en `Xamarin.Essentials API.` Se utiliza para verificar la información de la batería del dispositivo y monitorearlo en busca de cambios. `Android, iOS y UWP` ofrecen sistemas operativos únicos y API de plataforma a las que los desarrolladores tienen acceso en lenguajes `C #`, aprovechando Xamarin. **Xamarin.Essentials** proporciona una API multiplataforma única que funciona con cualquier aplicación `Xamarin.Forms, Android, iOS o UWP` a la que se pueda acceder desde un código compartido, sin importar cómo se cree la interfaz de usuario.

Por experiencia propia este link te dará la respuesta, y cómo realizarlo paso a paso: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/check-the-battery-information-in-xamarin-forms-application-using-xamarin-essenti/

Puedes traducir la página si no dominas el Inglés, espero haya sido de ayuda!